# Minimal primary decompositions of the zero ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, ideals

For a non-zero Noetherian ring $R$ let $P_1, . . . , P_r$ be its (pairwise different) prime
ideals that are associated to the zero ideal. Show that there is an integer
$n_0 ∈\mathbb N$ such that $\bigcap_{i=1}^{r}P^{(n)}_i =0$ for all $n ≥ n_0 $ and, hence, that the latter are
minimal primary decompositions of the zero ideal. $P^{(n)}_i$ means the symbolic power of a prime ideal.

My attempt, $x\in \bigcap_{i=1}^{r}P^{(n)}_i $ implies for every $i$, there exists $a_i \in R-P_i$, s.t. $a_ix \in P^{n}_i$. I tried to prove $x=y^m , y \in P_i,$ for every $i$. If that is true, then since the intersection of  $P_i$ is $\sqrt{(0)}$,  there exists $k$ s.t. $y^k=0$,  if $m>k$, we get $x=0$. But I don't know if it's the right direction or how to prove this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

$(0)$ has a primary decomposition. Let $Q$ be one of the primary ideals involved in it. Set $P=\sqrt Q$. Then there is $n_0\ge 1$ such that $P^n\subseteq Q$ for all $n\ge n_0$. We have $P^nR_P\subseteq QR_P$ and contracting to $R$ we get $P^{(n)}\subseteq Q$.

Now do this for all associated primes and then take the intersection.